# Reload event of ASP gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, reload

I am trying to fix some issues in an old asp.net application which uses ASP GridView. There are several events bound to the grid. Say sort, row click etc. I want to execute some js function after load/reload completes, (like after sort using header click etc.).

I tried

1. JQuery's ready function, which fires only on page load.
2. Placed a script block next to the grid
3. Placed a RegisterStartupScript in grid_sort (where DataBind happens)

none of them fires on grid reload after sort.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side events always cause a full page lifecycle.  But if there are `UpdatePanel`s in the mix then you may get a partial page postback which won't trigger a page load event. Keep in mind the full page lifecycle happens regardless.

When you want to execute some client side code after handling some sort of server side event, you need a way to pass some information to the JS/jQuery after the page fully renders.  Usually this is done by using 1 or more `<asp:HiddenField>` controls.

Typically I will set its ClientIDMode to static to make life easier on the JS side of things.  So for example if you have this:

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSomeData" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
      Value="Something set after handling some gridview event"
```

then you can do this on the javascript side to access the value:

```
  $("#hfSomeData").val();
```

The following code will execute `PostBackHandler` based on either the jquery ready event or call from `endRequest` as issued by an `UpdatePanel` partial page update

```
  // Handle Full Page postbacks
  $(function () {
    PostbackHandler(0);
  });

  // Handle Partial Page postbacks 
  //   i.e. when Gridview embedded in an UpdatePanel
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  prm.add_endRequest(function(sender, args){
    PostbackHandler(1);
  });

  //PostBackType    : 0 for Full Postback
  //                : 1 for Partial Postback
  function PostbackHandler(PostBackType) {

    var passed_in_data = $("#hfSomeData").val();

    if (PostBackType === 0)
      // do postback stuff
    else
      // do partial postback stuff    
  }
```